# Copying content of file in tibco using External Command palette

Tags: tibco-business-works

I want to copy content of one file to another file using External Command activity in Tibco BW.
I tried giving following commands

```
COPY "C:\New folder\FirstFile.txt" "C:\New folder\SecFile.txt"
```

and

```
type "C:\New folder\FirstFile.txt" >> "C:\New folder\SecFile.txt"
```

for both I am getting the same error

> "the system cannot find the file specified".

I tried same commands in Cmd they worked over there.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You want to try without spaces in the directory names?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cmd /c` before the command in windows.

Ex:

```
"cmd /c COPY "C:\New folder\FirstFile.txt" "C:\New folder\SecFile.txt"
```